# How do you determine when a Xamarin ContentPage is being destroyed?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way to determine if a Xamarin.Forms ContentPage is going to be destroyed?

The OnDisappearing event is fired off when a page is placed on top or if it is being destroyed.  But you never exactly know whether it is just being hidden or in the process of being destroyed.

Comment: @Jason it doesn't implement idisposable

Comment: Try the solution in this [comment](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/357728/#Comment_357728).

Comment: @JackHua broken link :(

Comment: because xamarin.forms page is a single activity. it is only destroyed when you exit from the app.